# Adobe Pro 9 Preflight gives error "The value for start page is too large (the file has less pages)"

Tags: pdf

Adobe Pro 9 opens and displays the PDF correctly. However when I attempt to do a preflight (I tried several of the different preflight options) I get the error "The value for start page is too large (the file has less pages)"

Opening the PDF in a text editor I found the kids array. The first entry is "10 0 R", which I assume is the "start page". I was able to find the "10 0" obj in the file, and to my untrained eye it looks okay.

Any suggestions on what is wrong with the PDF to cause this error?

Here is first line of the the kids array:

```
<</Count 600/Type/Pages/Kids[ 10 0 R 47 0 R 65 0 R 100 0 R 159 0 R 251 0 R 352 0 R 394 0 R 505 0 R 575 0 R 652 0 R 709 0 R 749 0 R 766 0 R 783 0 R 804 0 R 863 0 R 955 0 R 1056 0 R 1098 0 R 1209 0 R 1279 0 R 1356 0 R 1413 0 R 1453 0 R 1470 0 R 1487 0 R 1505 0 R 1564 0 R 1656 0 R 1757 0 R 1799 0 R 1910 0 R 1980 0 R 2057 0 R 2114 0 R 2154 0 R 2171 0 R 2188 0 R 2206 0 R 2265 0 R 2357 0 R 2458 0 R 2500 0 R 2611 0 R 2681 0 R 2758 0 R 2815 0 R 2855 0
```

Here is the 10 0 obj:

```
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 6 0 R
/Resources
<<
/Procset [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font 
<<
/Helvetica1 9 0 R
/Courier1 20 0 R
/myriadpro-regular.otf 25 0 R
/F1 28 0 R
/F3 31 0 R
/F2 34 0 R
/code25I.ttf 8 0 R
>>
/XObject 
<<
/img0 17 0 R
/img1 18 0 R
/img4 42 0 R
>>
/ColorSpace
<<
/RRDCS1 3 0 R
/RRDCS2 4 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0 0 864 1296]
/Contents [ 11 0 R 13 0 R 14 0 R 16 0 R 35 0 R 37 0 R 13 0 R 39 0 R 41 0 R 43 0 R 45 0 R]
>>
endobj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The PDF had been manipulated by an n-up program that broke the PDF into multiple files. Despite the PDF file only have about half the original pages, the program had left a reference to all the page files in the kids array. The PDF displayed correctly because Adobe just displayed all the pages it could find.